# CSS rule which keeps text elements in line with each other?

Tags: html, css

I'm not too familiar with CSS rules. I'm looking for the behaviour which is responsible for keeping elements within a table in line with one another, like this:

[image: In line]

See how the add to cart buttons are lined up properly? On my website, when I increase the length of the text of the product name for example, it would shift the add to basket button downwards, making the styling less attractive.

Which rules are applied to keep them in line, like this?

[image: still in line]

**Edit:** This example in specific is from a demo installation of Magento 1.9, I couldn't find a direct link but here is how you can access it:

1. http://installatron.com/magento/demo
2. Click on Shop Men
3. Click on New Arrivals

The code is actually enclosed within a div element containing a list. The class name is `product-grid first last odd`.

Comment: Set `min-height` of the product name element.

Comment: We can't say for sure without looking at the actual html

Comment: You say it's a table, so is it a`<table>`? In that case it might be as easy as hiving those buttons in a new `<tr>`? It sounds like you're trying to emulate an existing page, why not look how they do it?

Comment: My apologies for the vagueness. I've edited the question to point to the source page.

Comment: Demo link working Fine For me

Comment: Looks like it is already doing what you want? Or do you want to know how they did this?

Comment: This is done with responsive grids. Check them out. **EDIT**Also, the demo page, it is too big and is loading off the right of my screen..

Comment: @Andi trying to understand how they did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty quick, basic, snippet of how it works.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b1ydj8kw/)**

### EDIT

Changed code for OP's question. Works as desired.

```css
.item_img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 120px;
    background: red;
}
.item_text {
    max-width: 100px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
table, tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapsed;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="item_img"></td>
        <td class="item_img"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="item_text">Item Text</td>
        <td class="item_text">Item textItem textItem textItem textItem textItem textItem textItem textItem textItem textItem text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button>Add</button></td>
        <td><button>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your example doesn't work. Increase the name of the item that has a longer text's text by for instance 2 to 3 lines & you will see the `Add to Cart` buttons no longer line up.

Comment: If you make it auto scale to match ANY text length then you will run into issues with names that are too long. If you assign a max-height you want to abide by you can cut off text that would go out of bounds to reduce further pushdown of elements.

Comment: But then you're addressing a whole other issue which is user control. Your answer doesn't address the question though?

Comment: Changed my answer. Works as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Example here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdqk7L31/1/)

Wrap each div.item inside a div.wrapper with relative position. Then each div.item must contain a div.controls where your actions wil be placed.
Div.controls must have `position absolute; bottom: 0`, this way it will be always on bottom side of the relative parent wrapper element. The parent wrapper element will increase height according the dynamic content of any div.item.

```
.wrapper {position: relative} .controls {position: absolute; bottom: 0}
```

Each div.item must have a bottom space (padding-bottom) equal to the div.controls fixed height.
 `.item {padding-bottom: 100px} .controls {height: 100px}`

COMPLETE CODE HERE:

```
.wrapper {position: relative; overflow: hidden}
.item {width: 200px; padding-bottom: 100px; float: left; margin-right: 5px}
.item {border-left: 1px solid; border-right: 1px solid; border-top: 1px solid;} /* not relevant*/
.controls {position: absolute; bottom: 0%; width: 100%; height: 100px; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)}


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x160/000/fff">
    Lorem ipsum ......

    <div class="controls">
        <button>Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">

  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
</div>
```